# Add a stateless Widget in a String List

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to add a custom stateless widget after every string in a listView.
Is there a way to add a custom stateless widget after every item in a list of string or in a listView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var myStrings = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  foo() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {
      widgets.add(Text(myStrings[i]));
      widgets.add(Text('Your Custom Widget'));
    }
    return widgets;
  }
...
...

  ListView(
    children: foo(),
  )
```

Comment: that is what i wanted but is it possible to get the list of widgets as one string like one after the other. For now i am getting the widgets in a ListView which is ok but i have tried to return widgets.join()   and use it as a simple Text() but it gives me that output                                                                    Text("A")Text("my custom widget")Text("B")Text("my custom widget")...    i wand to have in this format A my custom widget B my custom widget and so on.

Comment: then simply do it `Text( myStrings[i] + 'my custom widget' ) `

Comment: if i do so  i am getting this output                                                                                
A Text(" my custom widget"),                                                                                               B Text(" my custom widget")                                                                                             C Text(" my custom widget")                                                                                               i want to have like this "A my custom widget B my custom Widget" all one after the other

Comment: `Text(  myStrings.join('my custom widget') )`

Comment: yes that is in the direction of what i want, but the problem is join() method accepts a string i want to put a widget in it.                                                                                                          i have tried to save my widget in a variable and then put that variable like so Text(  myStrings.join('$variable which contains my widget') ).   I got the same result like "A Text("my custom widget")) B Text("my custom widget")"